# why putchar('\b') not show back space?

Tags: c, io

```
void review2()
{
    int ch;
    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(ch);
    putchar('\b');
    putchar('\n');
    putchar('\007');
}
```

In this code, when I input "qweCtrl+DCtrl+D" is not show backspace.result is:

```
$ ./a.out
qweqwe
$
```

---

```
void review2()
{
    int ch;
    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(ch);
    putchar('\b');
    putchar('\007');
}
```

and in this code it's show back space.
result is

```
$ ./a.out
qweqw$
```

Why does this happen？

Comment: The backspace on screen is non-destructive, ie it does not overwrite what is already there in the first place. Try `putchar('\b');putchar(' ');putchar('\b');` to overwrite pre-existing data with a space

Comment: @pmg in second example, '\b' overwrite 'e', but in first example for some reason I don't know the putchar('\n') interupt this process.

Comment: No, the `'\b'` moves the "print position" on top the "e", In the second example the "e" is overwritten with the "$"; in the 1st case, the "e" is overwritten with the (invisible, transparent, logical) "\n"

Comment: ctrl-d is eot, not bs

Answer (score 0):

the backspace character just moves the cursor, it does not delete the displayed character on the display.